# Parsing JSON data to display it in gridview

Tags: java, android, json

I have created an application that parses data from URL to JSON object and displays it in a **GridView**.
Though errors shown are none, but every time I run the application I get the message **UNFORTUNATELY APPLICATION HAS STOPPED WORKING.**
Here are my application files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jsonparsernew;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Context context;
    private static String url = "http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json";

    private static final String VTYPE = "vehicleType";
    private static final String VCOLOR = "vehicleColor";
    private static final String FUEL = "fuel";
    private static final String TREAD = "treadType";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    GridView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private ListActivity activity;
        private Context context;

        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { VTYPE, VCOLOR, FUEL, TREAD }, new int[] {
                    R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel, R.id.treadType });

            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); // get JSON data from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtype = c.getString(VTYPE);
                    String vcolor = c.getString(VCOLOR);
                    String vfuel = c.getString(FUEL);
                    String vtread = c.getString(TREAD);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // Add child node to HashMap key & value

                    map.put(VTYPE, vtype);
                    map.put(VCOLOR, vcolor);
                    map.put(FUEL, vfuel);
                    map.put(TREAD, vtread);
                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream iStream = null;

    static JSONArray jarray = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        } // return JSON Object
        return jarray;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"> 

<!-- Main ListView Always give id value as list(@android:id/list) --> 

    <GridView
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical" > 

     <TextView android:id="@+id/vehicleType"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="vehicleType" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/vehicleColor"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="vehicleColor" /> 

     <TextView android:id="@+id/fuel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="fuel" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/treadType"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="treadType" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Buddy, can you post you logcat message?

Comment: Can you add more debugging statements like `Log.e("Something", some varialbe);`

Comment: did you apply internet permissions in Manifest file? like: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a similar answer here

[Iterating through json objects received from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238186/iterating-through-json-objects-received-from-the-server/25238776#25238776)

What you have in the JSON string is an ArrayList of Vehicles.
So you could do perhaps

```
public class Vehicle{
//properties and getters / setters
} 

public class MyResponse extends ArrayList<Vehicles> implements Serializable{}
```

I would also suggest using Volley for network requests.
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html