# Parsing JSONArray and showing the data in ListView in android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

In my android application I'm receiving a JSONArray and I'm parsing it and storing it in a arraylist and appending that to  listview but I'm facing an error entire list is showing in a single list item.but I'm receiving 4 items.This is all what I did.

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("topicsJSON",composeJSON());
          client.post("http://www.example.com/load_topics.php",params,newAsyncHttpResponseHandler()
    {

        public void onSuccess(String response)
        {


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            try 
            {

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
                {
                    //JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);

                    list.add(arr.get(i).toString());
                    load_data();


                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String content)

        {

            if (statusCode == 404) 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

            else if (statusCode == 500) 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

            else 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });



}

private String composeJSON() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> check_in_List;
    check_in_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("subject_code",received_subject_code);


    check_in_List.add(map);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    return gson.toJson(check_in_List);

}

public void load_data()
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> phy = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

    l1.setAdapter(phy);

    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text 

            String pos = (String) l1.getItemAtPosition(position);

    }); 

}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238866/parsing-json-data-to-display-it-in-gridview/25239036#25239036

Answer (score 1):

> I'm facing an error entire list is showing in a single list item.but
>   I'm receiving 4 items

Because calling `load_data();` inside `for-loop` which is used for getting  data from `JSONArray` in `ArrayList`

Move `load_data();` outside `for-loop` to show each item in separate row in ListView

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

try{
    JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("JSONArray Name");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(c.getString("Object Name"));
        }
}catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}

load_data();
```

Comment: Ok so make sure that ur list is full with data by print the size of list in Log and if it not working then you have to give the code of load_data().

Comment: it is returning the list size as 4 but its returning as JSON data in the listview

Comment: Can you give a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

don't every time add list item, create adapter,

set adapter one time with empty list.

after end parse Jsonarray and add data, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
            {
                //JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);

                list.add(arr.get(i).toString());
                load_data();


            }
```

Via

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
   {
           //JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);

           list.add(arr.get(i).toString());
    }
load_data();
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: this is not working bro,its showing 4 list items but its showing like 1st item,1st item 2 item,1st item 2 item,3 item and soo on...